# HHVM Configuration to "allow" case-insensitive constants

Tags: php, constants, hhvm

We run WordPress on HHVM and some plugins throw warnings because of case-insensitive constants, which means `define()` was used with the optional third argument `$case_insensitive = true`. AFAIK HHVM has never had and never will have actual support for case-insensitive constants, the warning indicates that despite compiling sucessfully the actual behavior will act as if the argument wasn't used.

While I recognize that case insensitive constants are stupid and it's fine to not have them, I also don't want to have to convince various third-party WP plugin developers to update their code for a platform (HHVM) they probably don't use. Forking plugins for stuff like this is a drain.

**SO: I'm hoping for a HHVM config that will silence these notices**

I'm willing to risk bugs if the developers actually take advantage of the case-insensitivity because I doubt they do and I can much more easily test to make sure they don't than manage a forked plugin forever.

If there is no config option I can live with that, but I couldn't find any answers via. Google, SO and ServerFault so I figured I'd be the one to ask and get a useful result built-up in SEO.

Example of the offending code:

`define("qq_enabled", "enabled", true);`

Example of a notice:

`Warning: Case insensitive constant names are not supported in HipHop in /var/www/sites/globalvoices_test/_plugins/quantcast-quantifier/quantcast-quantifier.php on line 52`

NOTE: I'm not asking for a way to **enable** case-insensitive constants, I accept that they are not supported for performance reasons. I just don't want to see warnings about them clogging up my logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

It's not possible to hide this message without changing HHVM and recompiling. But you can:

1. Set the `WarningFrequency` to a higher number to only print 1 in every N warnings https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/runtime-options

or

2. (My choice) Patch the WordPress plugins, notify the plugin authors, and keep a diff of your changes around so that you can apply it if you ever reinstall the plugin. It sucks, it's a drain, but this is how you fix the problem at the root. Also, most plugin developers should be open to fixing this for HHVM if they are given a working patch.

or

3. Use [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to split, compress, and automatically delete old logs.

### Exercise

As a fun exercise, I tracked through the HHVM code to see if it was actually possible to somehow disable this message without code changes.

Let's look at the code. This error is generated by calling `raise_warning(...)` ([source](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/1f9180e7c00a4d0c30dd806905effc3717b6713a/hphp/runtime/ext/std/ext_std_misc.cpp#L398-L400))

```
bool HHVM_FUNCTION(define, const String& name, const Variant& value,
              bool case_insensitive /* = false */) {
  if (case_insensitive) {
    raise_warning(Strings::CONSTANTS_CASE_SENSITIVE);
  }
  return Unit::defCns(name.get(), value.asCell());
}
```

`raise_warning(...)` is called whenever case_insensitive is true.  It is ONLY called with a string representing the error message (defined in the header file). This doesn't look too good, so far, there is no easy way to uniquely identify this message down in raise_warning so it is probably not going to be able to be filtered using a standard process. Let's see what `raise_warning(...)` actually does though.  ([source](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/d6ce5612bb55a642b5a1522ef3d6650abe74817b/hphp/runtime/base/runtime-error.cpp#L202-L206))

```
void raise_warning(const std::string &msg) {
  if (warning_freq_check()) {
    raise_warning_helper(false, msg);
  }
}
```

`raise_warning(...)` makes a call to `warning_freq_check()` which basically determines if the warning should be logged, is allows you to only print every N warnings as well.

As you can tell, there is no unique way of identifying this message from any other message at this point in the code. The message gets set with the WARNING level. Apart from the frequency check (which just prevents a ton of the same message from being printed)

Additional, **not recommended** options include

1. Removing the `raise_warning()` call in `ext_std_misc.cpp` and recompile hhvm
2. Restricting the logging level until this warning is silenced (https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/runtime-options)

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! Highly appreciate that you took the time to look in the code for reasons and try to find an actual fix for me! I am satisfied with 2 (fix plugins) and hope this post+answer will help anyone else wondering about what's going on and whether there is an easy solution :)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! I too hope that this answer helps others!